# Scroll to top button redirecting to Homepage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So, this script is on my footer.php, and when button is pressed it redirects to homepage instead of top.

`$(document).ready(function() {`
    `$("#arriba").click(function() {`
        `return $("html, body").animate({`
            `scrollTop: 0`
        `}, 1250), !1`
    `})`
`});`

**UPDATE:**
Thanks so much all, I found the solution, the code above was inserted into a php instance, I created a new javascript instance out of the php and it's working fine all the codes presented here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use preventDEfault to stop behavior of your button or anchor tag:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#arriba").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 1250);
        })
    });
```

EDIT:

try also this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#arriba").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault()
         window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    })
});
```

Comment: Did you copy my snipper correctly? I have made some changes to your original code.

Comment: Sorry man! The error was all mine. I was inserting the script inside a php variable like <?php ?>, I created a new javascript variable and it's working well now!

Comment: I was thinking just the sane that's  why I have asked you if you copied the code correctly, because I have test it in my playground and was working. If this was useful for you please accept the answer so also other user seeking for the same can find it.

Comment: My old script is working well out of the php instance, thanks man, I appreciate!